# How to prevent elements from blinking on each API call in an interval while data is updating

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, setinterval

A JSON array got from an API call is supposed to be displayed in cards using ionic 5 and Rxjs.
The API is being called every 5 seconds, so the data will be changed on each call. 
The problem is that on each call the whole cards will be regenerated and looks bilking to the user.
Here is how I'm calling the API:

```
interval(1 * 5 * 1000)
.pipe(
    flatMap(() => this.myService.getList())
)
.subscribe(res => {
  if(res){this.list = res.history;}
})
```

In html file, the data is displayed on cards using "ion-virtual-scroll" like below:

```
<ion-virtual-scroll [items]="list" approxItemHeight="132px">
  <ion-item *virtualItem="let q">
    <!-- cards will go hear -->
  </ion-item>
</ion-virtual-scroll>
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it's been fixed, by adding itemHeight, so the code in html file would be:

```
<ion-virtual-scroll [items]="filteredList" approxItemHeight="152px" [itemHeight]="itemHeightFn"> ...
```

and in .ts file:

```
itemHeightFn(item, index) {return 182;}
```

So, the virtual scroll doesn't make items blinking while getting updated. It solved the issue in my case since all my items have the same height.

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Good one. Actually the doc says thus: "An optional function that maps each item within their height. When this function is provides, heavy optimizations and fast path can be taked by ion-virtual-scroll leading to massive performance improvements. This function allows to skip all DOM reads, which can be Doing so leads to massive performance"

If you look beyond the poor grammar, doc above does provide adequate hints for one to give it a try and see what happens. But the trouble is who reads documentations so carefully to spot these subtle hints..

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `distinctUntilChanged` operator to prevent any unnecessary DOM update. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help as all the items in the list get updated on each call.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Angular's "trackBy" function to achieve this:
https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

This is also mentioned in the documentation for ion-virtual-scroll:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/virtual-scroll#changing-dataset-should-use-trackby

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although it works perfectly on ngFor, unfortunately it doesn't help in ion-virtual-scroll. Same issue still exists when using ion-virtual-scroll.